# Extending a static factory method pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I have an existing code base that uses a static [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) design for instantiating certain object types:

```
public static Something createSomething(int x, int y, .....)
{
    // creates a Something object
}
```

I'd like to extend this method by allowing it to initializing a Something object in a different way, based on new parameter(s) that will dictate how the object is created.

The simplest (and least scalable) way would be to add new parameters to the factory method.

This doesn't seem like the right way for doing things:

1. There's more than 1 factory method that needs to be updated, not just one.
2. Creating a new method would force changing client code that calls the factory. This sort of defeats the purpose of having a single location that generates objects.
3. Adding more parameters makes for long parameter lists that are uneasy to use.

**Is there a better approach for extending a factory method ?**

Comment: Use the Builder pattern.

Comment: care to elaborate (even briefly) how that fits the requirements and allows extending current design?

Comment: It wouldn't be extending it. You would have to modify the current design to use a Builder object instead of the Factory. The simplest way would just be adding a new method with an extra parameter.

Comment: I agree, however the simplest way may not be the best way.

Comment: You say it doesn't seem like the right way. Could you elaborate ? You could add another method with a different name, and not doing any overloading, also.

Comment: Could you just create a wrapper around existing factory methods so that you can modify the result before returning it?

Comment: Added few reasons why (i think) adding more parameters as you need to update the factory functionality is perhaps not the greatest way. One could argue with these though.

Comment: @trevor-e i may be able to do so, although the methods are currently static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an new method, and use a parameter object as argument ([Is this a named pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173862/is-this-a-named-pattern)). This way, you don't change the previous implementation, and you are open to any new implementation (you change the parameter object without affecting currently existing calls to the method).

Additional thoughts : yes, this way, you have two methods, but if you do it right, it's not a problem :

```
public static Something createSomething(int x, int y, .....)
{
    /// 1. Implementation
    /// OR
    /// 2. return createSomething(new SomethingDescription(parameters ...));
}

public static Something createSomething(SomethingDescription description)
{
    /// 1. return createSomething(description.x, description.y, ...);
    /// OR
    /// 2. Implementation
}
```

But if the object is truly complex, and can be build in a lot of ways, you should rather switch to Builder pattern, as suggested by Sotirios Delimanolis.